# path alias hook menu i18n

Tags: 7, path-aliases, i18n-l10n

Is it possible to make path alias that is not storing in database, like using system hook menu path I want to make url for en/weather and rs/vreme.

e.g

```
<?php
function weather_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['weather'] = array(
      'title' => 'title',
      'description' => t('description hook menu'),
      'page callback' => 'weather_page',
      'access callback' => TRUE,
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
     return $items;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to add path aliases to "weather" menu path

- Enable locale module
- Go to admin/config/search/path/add
- Select language rs and add path alias as "vreme" and Existing system path as "weather"

That should work !:-)

Comment: yes i know that, but i want to make system path.
e.g. if i want rebuild url alias table i also have to make manually all aliases i have 4 languages and this few similar pages

Comment: What do you mean by system path ? Do you want to return different data for rs language and different data for english language ? using two different menu callbacks for different languages...

Comment: sorry anil i posted before i finished the reply. 
i mean default $items['weather'] path or arg(0)

Comment: Why cannot you use basic page that supports locale so that you can associate all 4 languages nodes together ? what is the data you are returning in page callback ? Is it just html ?

Comment: dynamic data in different languages. I'm parsing JSON data in different languages, and i also want because of SEO

Comment: Not sure i understand your problem, here are my suggestions... Either you create multiple menu path items and check global $language in menu callback or use single menu path and create aliases for them...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I know perfectly what you mean. This is a nightmare in Drupal, to be frank. I don't know why we cannot filter aliases by their module signature and bulk operations are destructive to manually created aliases... But anyway:

If this is a non-Views page, in `hook_init()` of a module, you could check if the alias exists and if not, create it using [path_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/path_save/7). Then bind it into a path translation set via [i18n_translation_set_create()](http://drupal.org/node/1114010)

If this is a Views-generated page you could give a try to http://drupal.org/project/i18_page_views.